# How to use github libraries that has no gradle installation?

Tags: android, android-studio

I've seen lots of libraries in github that has no dependencies for adding them to a project.

The questions are:

1. How can I use these libraries?
2. How can I add them to my project?

For instance, this is a gitbub project that I don't know how to use those:
https://github.com/zzhouj/Android-SlidingUpPanel

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you would download a JAR file - if any - or download the project and build the JAR yourself (like you would do for Volley project). But if there is no JAR support, like Android-SlidingUpPanel, just download it and add it as a module in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this way;

download `android-support-v4.jar`, add to your **LIBS** folder,

build project.